# Coin tossing - Two tosses, one is a head, probability other is a tail?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, bayesian

A friend of mine tossed a fair coin twice. Suppose instead that I happen to see the result of one of his tosses, and it is a head. What is the probability that the other toss is tail?

Comment: This is the same as your other question (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/299500/coin-toss-probability-of-a-tail-known-that-one-is-heads) if you don't know which of the two tosses you saw - the first or the second. If you know which toss you saw, then the probability is $1/2$